# Android - Open local image uri with action_view intent

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, actionview

I'm working on old Android Java app. Now I've a problem with an image opening through action_view intent. I've the image saved locally at context.getFilesDir()/myDir/myImage.png path and I've setup a provider.

For opening the image I do this:

```
File imagePath = new File(requireContext().getFilesDir(), "myDir");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, miImage.getFilename());
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(requireContext(), requireContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", newFile);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
requireContext().grantUriPermission(requireContext().getPackageName(), contentUri, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
i.setData(contentUri);
```

startActivity(i);

All seems to work, but unfortunately after selecting the gallery app I didn't see the image but only an infinite loader.

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

P.S. The app is built with Android 10 sdk.

Comment: if(!newFile.exists()) return; Display a toast too to inform the user.

Comment: Use setDataAndType() instead adding a mime type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide, it permits to manage image

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
 mFavDishDetails?.let {
        if (it.id != 0) {
            mImagePath = it.image

            // Load the dish image in the ImageView.
            Glide.with(this@AddUpdateDishActivity)
                .load(mImagePath)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(mBinding.ivDishImage)

            mBinding.etTitle.setText(it.title)
            mBinding.etType.setText(it.type)
            mBinding.etCategory.setText(it.category)
            mBinding.etIngredients.setText(it.ingredients)
            mBinding.etCookingTime.setText(it.cookingTime)
            mBinding.etDirectionToCook.setText(it.directionToCook)

            mBinding.btnAddDish.text = resources.getString(R.string.lbl_update_dish)
        }


  /**
 * Receive the result from a previous call to
 * {@link #startActivityForResult(Intent, int)}.  This follows the
 * related Activity API as described there in
 * {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)}.
 *
 * @param requestCode The integer request code originally supplied to
 *                    startActivityForResult(), allowing you to identify who this
 *                    result came from.
 * @param resultCode The integer result code returned by the child activity
 *                   through its setResult().
 * @param data An Intent, which can return result data to the caller
 *               (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
 */
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA) {

            data?.extras?.let {
                val thumbnail: Bitmap =
                    data.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap // Bitmap from camera

                // Set Capture Image bitmap to the imageView using Glide
                Glide.with(this@AddUpdateDishActivity)
                    .load(thumbnail)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(mBinding.ivDishImage)

                mImagePath = saveImageToInternalStorage(thumbnail)
                Log.i("ImagePath", mImagePath)

                // Replace the add icon with edit icon once the image is loaded.
                mBinding.ivAddDishImage.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this@AddUpdateDishActivity,
                        R.drawable.ic_vector_edit
                    )
                )
            }
        } else if (requestCode == GALLERY) {

            data?.let {
                // Here we will get the select image URI.
                val selectedPhotoUri = data.data

                // Set Selected Image URI to the imageView using Glide
                Glide.with(this@AddUpdateDishActivity)
                    .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                        override fun onLoadFailed(
                            @Nullable e: GlideException?,
                            model: Any?,
                            target: Target<Drawable>?,
                            isFirstResource: Boolean
                        ): Boolean {
                            // log exception
                            Log.e("TAG", "Error loading image", e)
                            return false // important to return false so the error placeholder can be placed
                        }

                        override fun onResourceReady(
                            resource: Drawable,
                            model: Any?,
                            target: Target<Drawable>?,
                            dataSource: DataSource?,
                            isFirstResource: Boolean
                        ): Boolean {

                            val bitmap: Bitmap = resource.toBitmap()

                            mImagePath = saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap)
                            Log.i("ImagePath", mImagePath)
                            return false
                        }
                    })
                    .into(mBinding.ivDishImage)

                // Replace the add icon with edit icon once the image is selected.
                mBinding.ivAddDishImage.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this@AddUpdateDishActivity,
                        R.drawable.ic_vector_edit
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.e("Cancelled", "Cancelled")
    }
}
```

Github repo

https://github.com/wilson1234567891962/Complete-Android-11-Jetpack-Masterclass